# Voice action inside a Python-3.x if / elif

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am starting small with Python. In itself I am putting together an application that is similar to Alexa, Jarvis, Cortana, among others in the aspect of automating actions through voice.

Python version: Python 3.10.0

I am using these libraries:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import urllib.request
import json
import datetime
import wikipedia
```

My problem is that when I tell the "BOT" or application to send a message to "x" person it does not recognize the action it should do, I leave my code here

```py
    elif 'send message to ' in rec:
        if 'dad' in rec == True:
            msj = rec.replace('message to dad', '')
            talk('Sending message to dad...' + msj)
            print(dad, msj)
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(dad, msj, 20)
        elif 'mom' in rec == True:
            msj = rec.replace('message to mom', '')
            talk('Sending message to mom...' + msj)
            print(mom, msj)
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(mom, msj, 20)
```

The variables `mom` and `dad` have an assigned number of each.
The action `pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly` sends a message automatically by WhatsApp
The action `msg = rec.replace ('message to xx', '')` replaces the initial text in this case "message to mom" with an empty message so that the bot does not repeat that. Only send what has been said after the variable msg an example: "Message to mom" -> "Hello mom" <- this sends the bot

If the problem is that it does not recognize me when I say "Bot sends message to xx or xx"

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `== True` from your conditions.

Python comparisons chain, so `'dad' in rec == True` means `('dad' in rec) and (rec == True)`. That condition will never succeed in your program.

Just use `if 'dad' in rec:` and `elif 'mom' in rec:`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so remove what you told me to remove, but it still does not work :/ 

```elif 'send message to' in rec:
        if 'mom' in rec:
            msj = rec.replace('message to mom', '')
            talk('Sending message to mom...' + msj)
            print(mom, msj)
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(mom, msj, 20)
        elif 'dad' in rec:
            msj = rec.replace('Message to dad', '')
            talk('Sending message to dad...' + msj)
            print(dad, msj)
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(dad, msj, 20)```

Comment: If `if 'mom' in rec:` doesn't work, then the substring `mom` does not occur in `rec`. There's nothing in your the code you have posted to indicate what `rec` is or whether it contains what you want it to contain. I suggest you print `rec` out and see what it actually is.

Comment: oh, check my code pls https://paiza.io/projects/4r8r8mvNs_Htn2Fk4TfxYQ  You can see the code online to see if I have written it right, thanks!!!

Comment: In the code you linked you are checking `if 'Send message to' in rec`, which can never be true because `rec` is in lower case. If you have more problems with your code, you should post a new question with a [mre]. Questions that rely on outside code are not useful for future readers.

Comment: Ready, I have corrected it and I left it with a lowercase